# Не работает проверка IF/ELSE

Tags: python

Всем добрый день,осваиваю питон,пользуюсь *OrangePI + Armbian(Ubuntu Baster)*
Имеется такой код для определения температуры CPU и вывода на 1602

```
def main():
      while True: 
        set_temp = get_cpu_temp()
        nowtime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        update_LCD(nowtime,set_temp)
        sleep(1) 
        
def update_LCD(time,get_temp):   
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(2)+time, 1)
        if get_temp < 49:
            print('low')
            mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(0)+get_temp, 2)
        elif temp > 49:
            print('high')
            mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(1)+get_temp, 2)
```

Почему-то независимо от температуры,выводится **high**, что я делаю не так?Подскажите пожалуйста.
При этом саму температуру на дисплей выводит нормально.
Функция вывода температуры:

```
def get_cpu_temp():
    tmp = open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp')
    cpu = tmp.read()
    tmp.close()
    return '{:.0f}'.format(float(cpu) / 1000)
```

P.S такой вариант тоже не работает

```
def update_LCD(temp, time,get_temp):   
    mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(2)+time, 1)
    if temp < 50:
        print('low '+temp)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(0)+get_temp, 2)
    else:
        print('high '+temp)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(chr(1)+get_temp, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому что из `get_cpu_temp()` приходит строка, а сравниваете вы с числом.

Comment: Хм,а почему проверка на число выдает true тогда?
`def is_digit(string):
    if string.isdigit():
       return True
    else:
        try:
            float(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False`
И как мне получить число вместо строки?

Comment: Потому что это не проверка на число.

Comment: И вам не нужно получать число вместо строки, т.к. у вас уже изначально число. Вам нужно из get_cpu_temp() возвращать это число, а не форматировать, как это делаете вы. А если где-то потребуется строка, то там на месте и конвертировать.

Comment: Сделал так вывод return format(float(cpu) / 1000)   как понял это должно быть числом,но все равно не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Сработал такой вариант получения температуры по совету [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA)

```
tFile = open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp')
temp = float(tFile.read())
tempC = temp/1000
tFile.close()
return tempC
```